# Winform On Top without Losing Focus

Tags: c#, winforms

I am writing a Settings form for one of my applications. Once the user clicks Tool > Settings a new form comes up with the settings that can be changed.

The **TopMost** property is set the **True** and working properly.

What I can't seem to find how to do is to keep the Form on focus. I do not want the use to be able to leave the form. The user has to close the form to continue using the application.

Thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using `Show()` to show the settings form. Instead, use `ShowDialog()`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Display it like this:

```
FormChild1 Child = new FormChild1();
Child.ShowDialog(this);
```